# Error in Connection with two different DB - PHP LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a Laravel project.

I have two different databases (ie) different username and password for each database.
When I use joins in a Laravel query, it throws an error saying that a database username can't connect with others.

Can anyone please tell me how to use joins with two different databases in Laravel?

Comment: It's possible the user you use to connect to a given database does not have access for the database/table you wish to join to. I don't think this is a Laravel issue but one inherent with the permissions system of MySQL. Are you sure the user can access both databases independently (regardless of joining)?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by assuming you have two connections in your `config\database.php`:

```
...
'db1' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'database'  => 'db1',
     ...
],

'db2' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'database'  => 'db2',
     ...
],
...
```

In your Eloquent models, you have to specify the connection which you will use, through a protected attribute.

```
class tableInDb1 extends Eloquent {
    protected $connection = "db1";
}
```

During your queries, you can create your join as you usually do.

```
$myQuery = tableInDb1::join('tableInDb2','id','=','id');
```

**Or**

You can skip the `$connection` attribute and attach the connection on the fly:

```
$myQuery = tableInDb1::on('db1')->join('tableInDb2','id','=','id');
```

**Semi-Related:**

If you are creating relationships that are using different databases, add the database's name to the `table` attribute, as such:

```
class myTable extends Eloquent {
    protected $connection = "db1";
    protected $table = "db1.myTable";
}
```

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#basic-usage